# Can't enable notifications in angular 4 , using firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making an angular 4 app and now I want to enable push notifications. I am using firebase for getting push notifications, as I already used it in authentication.

I do something like:
I am not infect getting inside from "receiveMessage"function. What to do to enable push notifications.

```
 messaging = firebase.messaging()

 receiveMessage() {
       this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
        console.log("Message received. ", payload);
        this.currentMessage.next(payload)
      });
```

Comment: Nothing you shared is calling `receiveMessage()`, so that might explain why you're not getting into the callback?

Comment: I called it on constructor, i want to trigger when data is inserted to my firebase db.

Comment: You're using the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK. While both Database and FCM are part of Firebase, they don't automatically communicate. Receiving data from the database requires that you [add a listener from that SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events).

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to make a call for receiveMessage in your app.component.ts. This will enable the app to activate the listener once the app is loaded